# Do you use pure or impure functions in your React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

So i've been getting a little bit more into functional programming and immutability.

What I often do when writing a react component is a helper function that returns something based on props/state.

Currently I write both Pure and Impure functions even though most of them could be pure.

Examples for both cases:

```js
//pure function
const posts = this.props.posts;
const postId = this.props.selectedPostId;
const pureFunc = (postId, posts) => (posts.find(post => post.id === postId);

//impure function
const impureFunc = () => (
      this.props.posts.find(
          post => post.id === this.props.selectedPostId
      )
)
```

Please, let's refrain from commenting on the overall structure and validity of the code.

The main point of comparison is to pass arguments and operate on those OR pass something from `this` context which is not like a global state, but it does feel a lot less like functional programming.

What do you prefer and think?

Comment: `this` is a dynamic binding and is used in OO patterns, not functional ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the second approach you're combining OOP-like and function styles, so it's not truly functional.

It's possible to avoid using the `this` context altogether by writing stateless react components, which are essentially pure functions.

If that's not possible, I would suggest using the first approach - that is, passing the props to the function, not letting the function itself access the `this` context.

Comment: I can't upvote your answer due to low rep, but thanks for your opinion. Yes I realize that the latter approach is more of a hybrid. I try to use functional components where possible however I always endup with some kind of container component for all the handlers.